# What does Properties(Properties default) do?

Tags: java, properties

What does this statement do :-

Properties props = new Properties(Properties default)

When I use :-

```
Properties props = new Properties (System.getProperties());
```

I get the size of `props` to be Zero
but when I write something like this :-

```
Properties props = System.getProperties()
```

I get some non-zero size for `props`

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#Properties%28java.util.Properties%29

Comment: Yes, I have seen that, but what does the line convey, create an empty properties list with specified defaults?

Comment: In the class doc, it says: "A property list can contain another property list as its "defaults"; this second property list is searched if the property key is not found in the original property list. "

Comment: Then read this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#getProperty%28java.lang.String%29

Answer (score 1):

The newly created properties will be empty, but resort to looking up values in the `default` on misses. It will *not* eagerly populate your new properties with the default values; it is not a copy constructor.